# rails app not redirecting unkown url to 404 page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404

my rails 6 app is not redirecting unknown urls to the default rails 404 page.
Instead it shows redirection errors on the browser.
Should I add some code to routes file? Isnt this functionality comes by default with a new rails installation? what may be wrong?

***routes.rb***

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  post "static_pages/home"
  post "static_pages/go_tafqit"

  constraints(subdomain: '') do
    get "(*x)" => redirect { |params, request|
      URI.parse(request.url).tap { |x| x.host = "#{x.host}" }.to_s
    }
  end
  end
```

***application_Controller.rb***

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

[image]

Comment: Likely something with the setup isn't resolving when trying to find the 404 page but it is impossible to tell without any relevant code.  Likely it also happens locally too,  test it there and then you can see in the logs what is causing it to keep redirecting over and over

Comment: it does happen locally too indeed. when i enter an invalid url it keeps on getting it.

Started GET "/abouts" for ::1 at 2020-12-27 01:54:13 +0200
Started GET "/abouts" for ::1 at 2020-12-27 01:54:14 +0200
Started GET "/abouts" for ::1 at 2020-12-27 01:54:14 +0200
...
keeps generating that line until i stop the server ..

Comment: Do you have any kind of catch-all in your application that could be causing an infinite redirect?

Comment: Can you share any code related to redirecting this?  Is `/about` a valid URL for your app or is that the invalid URL you are putting in?

Comment: @max no, nothing am aware of

Comment: @RockwellRice I am a noob in rails, and don't think I  have changed anything of the default configs, I dont know if this issue has been there since I built this app 6 years ago, or it started after some rails upgrades later on...
as for the url am using for the log is abouts (note the extra s at the end) instead of about just an example of wrong url that is causing this

Comment: There is something causing the redirects.  Can you edit the question with your `routes.rb` file and `application_controller.rb` file?  What controller handles the about page?  Is there a `before_action` or `before_filter` (if it is old) of some kind?

Comment: @RockwellRice I've updated the question with code of routes.rb and application_controller.rb

Comment: You don't need `application.rb` in there, that isn't related at all.  That subdomain redirect, are all URLS for the site suppose to have a subdomain?  If not can you try to just reomve that once and try that `aouts` route to see if it works,  I feel like that is the culprite.

Comment: @RockwellRice do you mean i should try to remove the block that starts with constraints(subdomain: '') do. 
I don't recall why I have added that.. maybe the site was not redirecting http to https? am not sure...I dont need a subdomain on my site..

anyway I have tried to remove that code and now it shows me a rails error on the browser whenever I open any invalid page example when openning /abouts (with s): No route matches [GET] "/abouts"

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution for 404 rendering:

`match "*path", to: "errors#path_not_found", via: :all`

- "errors" is the controller for handling different types of errors
- "path_not_found" -> is the controller's method to render and the
  static page to render

Instead of match you "might" use "get" (remove "via: :all" as well), but I use "match" to catch all the trashy-requests (get, patch, post, delete) from bots.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following line to ***routes.rb***

```
get '*path' => redirect('/404.html')
```

and removed

```
constraints(subdomain: '') do
    get "(*x)" => redirect { |params, request|
      URI.parse(request.url).tap { |x| x.host = "#{x.host}" }.to_s
    }
```

working fine now.